# Was Constable Zuvio in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, character-identification

Constable Zuvio has his own page on [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/constable-zuvio) and [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zuvio) and even a Black Series toy.

[image: On the left a picture of the Constable Zuvio action figure, on the right the same action figure in its "Star Wars The Black Series" box]

## Was Constable Zuvio even in *The Force Awakens*?

If so, when did he show up and what did he do?

Comment: This guy is like the Toad of toy stores: "thank you, but our Stormtroopers are in another castle!".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### He was supposed to be in it, but his scene was cut at some point.

The canonical [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/constable-zuvio) *claims* he appears in the film:

> ### Constable Zuvio
>
> What’s an honorable Kyuzo like Constable Zuvio doing on a lawless planet like Jakku? The tough, taciturn Zuvio is the leader of Niima Outpost’s small militia, and keeps a wary yellow eye out for cheats, thieves and others bent on trouble. He is often found guarding Niima’s landing field, glowering at any local who strays too close to a visitor’s starship.
>
> *Appearances*: Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens

So he definitely exists in canon. He also has a canon novel (*High Noon on Jakku*, part of the TFA series) devoted to him, and he's also shown in the *Visual Dictionary*:

[image: 2-page spread from the "Star Wars Visual Dictionary" showing the entry for "Niima Outpost." An annotated half-page image of Constable Zuvio features prominently.]

According to [this article](https://www.slashfilm.com/541763/who-is-constable-zuvio/), he was *going* to have a scene in the film, but it was deleted:

> The scene in which Contable Zuvio was to appear in the film would have taken place right after the thugs attack Rey in an attempt to abduct BB-8. From what I’ve heard, local peacekeeper Constable Zuvio “steps in to break up the tussle.” After settling the issue with the Constable, Rey heads back to her dwelling, “keenly aware that the dastardly Unkar would like nothing better than to get his hands on her new droid.” From what gleam, the moment with the thugs plays out differently in the film as originally Finn (FN-2187) had not yet escaped from the First Order at that point. BB-8 recognizing Finn originally happened the next day.

He also doesn't get mentioned in the official novelisation.

---

The good Constable must be somewhat pissed off about all this:

[image: A Zuvio action figure is posed on a windowsill; the caption reads "We'll put you in the pictures they said. You'll be famous they said."]

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't just throw him in the background with the rest of the random aliens around Unkar's place.

Comment: The aptly named Sir-not-appearing-in-this-film... Now we have his photo and he's an alien!

Comment: Perhaps he's lurking in the background somewhere. We'll have to wait until the DVD comes out.